# Cannot filter data when space using Filter method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using this filter function in pipe in angular

```
transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    if(!value)return null;
    if(!args)return value;
      if(!value)return null;
      if(!args)return value;
      args = args.toLowerCase();
      return value.filter(function(item){
          return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(args);
      });
}
```

It will check both the type of keys

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "Ashish",
        "LastName": "Kumar",
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Pawan",
        "LastName": "Verma",
    },
    ...
    ...
]
```

or

```
  [
        {
            "Name": "Ashish Kumar",
        },
        {
            "Name": "Pawan Verma",
        },
        ...
        ...
    ]
```

In my case if i pass space like `Ashish`  then the data is not matched

`let user of Info |SearchUser:Search`

in case of this one

```
  {
            "FirstName": "Ashish",
            "LastName": "Kumar",
        },
```

for this   `"Name": "Ashish Kumar",..` the record is displayed

Comment: `.filter` itself works great the fault is yours. What you want to filter, please say clearly

Comment: @TachibanaShin I have both the above data with two different structures through which i'm searching if it matches with `Name` OR `FirstName` and `LastName` that data should be returned

Comment: what is type `args`, `value`?

Comment: @TachibanaShin value is array of objects and args is simple string that we need to compare

Comment: type has it in typescript for example `interface Value { name: string }`

Answer (score 0):

asuming that the objects in value are depth 1, you can do this instead:

```
transform(value: any[], search?: string): any[] | null {
    if (!value) return null;
    if (!search) return value;
    const lowerSearch = search.toLowerCase(); // could trim this here.
    return value.filter(item => {
        for(let key in item){
            // if you want to ignore leading/trailing spaces do
            // if(item[key].toLowerCase?.().includes(lowerSearch.trim()))
            if(item[key].toLowerCase?.().includes(lowerSearch))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    
}
```